# Flex ItemRenderer Images not appearing at runtime

Tags: apache-flex, image, runtime, itemrenderer

in datagrid I have an ItemRenderer (which extends UIComponent) which loads images based on a data value, eg:

```
 _img.source = "assets/images/flags/" + value[dglistData.dataField] + ".gif";
```

When I run my application the images (flags) are appearing in the ItemRenderer. When I build and deploy the application into BlazeDS as an SWF file - the images do not appear. Instead there is the standard "missing icon" link that appears in Internet explorer.

As far as I can tell, my ANT build script includes the above directory "assets/images/flags/" and all the images into the SWF file.

Is this a relative path issue? Not sure, any help would be appreaciated.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are assigning a path as `source` Flash Player is trying to load the images via HTTP requests. Therefore, embedding your images in the SWF has no effect.

There are two possible solutions. Either deploy the folder containing your images to the server and use the corresponding path as your `source` or embed all your images into the SWF.

A simple example for the second solution. The code assumes that `value[dglistData.dataField]` corresponds to one of the variables with the `[Embed]` metadata.

```
[Embed(source='assets/images/flags/Image1.png')]
private var image1:Class;

[Embed(source='assets/images/flags/Image2.png')]
private var image2:Class;

[Embed(source='assets/images/flags/Image3.png')]
private var image3:Class;

// access the image like this...
_img.source = this[value[dglistData.dataField]];
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I copied Michael's example and forgot to delete this part. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Gerhard, thanks for answer. I do like the second solution using the [Embed] tag. I do have a lot of images to load, about 75 flags in all and rather than typing each [Embed] tag out is there a way to load & cache the images dynamically? This would also help when more images are added I would not have to change any of my code. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunatly you can either load the images at runtime (AFAIK the browser caches those images like it does with every other web resource) or embed the images in your SWF (which in your case means you have to type 75 [Embed] statements). You have to choose one of them... If you don't want to change your code when you add more images you should load the images at runtime.